# How to make streaming requests with Fetch API?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm trying to use the Fetch API to stream requests to an express backend.  I always receive `TypeError: Failed to fetch`, and I'm not sure how to debug at this point.  Here's my backend:

```
// src/index.js
const express = require('express')
const port = 3030;
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('static'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => { res.sendFile('index.html') });

app.post('/api', (req, res) => { res.send('Hello World!') });

app.listen(port, () => {});
```

Here's my frontend, in which I make the fetch POST request:

```
// static/index.html
<script>
  const wait = (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
  async function start() {
    const stream = new ReadableStream({
      async start(controller) {
        await wait(1000);
        controller.enqueue("This ");
        await wait(1000);
        controller.enqueue("is ");
        await wait(1000);
        controller.enqueue("slow.");
        controller.close();
      },
    }).pipeThrough(new TextEncoderStream());
    await fetch("/api", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "text/plain" },
      body: stream,
      duplex: "half",
    });
  }
</script>
<button onclick="start()">Click me</button>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.